# Html with Google apps script.

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-apps

I just start to play around with Google Html service, but I cant seem to get my project off the ground. I pieced together this code from the Google examples, but I cant get it to work. In a script document i have 2 files one is called Code.gs the other is Map.html. When I publish this script as a web App and then run it the page comes up black. I know that it is kinda working because if i insert a

Hello world

into the body, the web page shows Hello World. Bellow is the code for Code.gs and Map.html respectively

```
function doGet() { 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Map');
}
```

black

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City',   'Population', 'Area'],
        ['Rome',      2761477,    1285.31],
        ['Milan',     1324110,    181.76],
        ['Naples',    959574,     117.27],
        ['Turin',     907563,     130.17],
        ['Palermo',   655875,     158.9],
        ['Genoa',     607906,     243.60],
        ['Bologna',   380181,     140.7],
        ['Florence',  371282,     102.41],
        ['Fiumicino', 67370,      213.44],
        ['Anzio',     52192,      43.43],
        ['Ciampino',  38262,      11]
      ]);

      var options = {
        region: 'IT',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange, your page works when when I paste it into jsfiddle.net

Comment: I know, I put it into the jsfiddle.net as well and it worked. I must be going something wrong with passing it thought the google apps script... but i did it exactly like it was on the google website

Answer (score 2):

This is because the library you using is not supported by caja. Caja is a engine that it will be used to check before it can be displayed to the user and currently, it support JQuery and JQuery UI, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja. So if you wish to test you code, you might want to go *http://caja.appspot.com/* and test it.

Comment: Truth is, besides  JQuery and JQuery UI that Caja is designed to support, every other library will fail miserably. Unless it is a pretty damn basic thing that you can probably write yourself faster than searching on google and downloading the lib.